# How to get total count result for following table?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Table Looks like this

```
╔══════╦══════╗
║ COL1 ║ COL2 ║
╠══════╬══════╣
║ A    ║ abc  ║
║ A    ║ dce  ║
║ A    ║ xyz  ║
║ B    ║ abc  ║
║ B    ║ xyz  ║
║ C    ║ abc  ║
║ C    ║ www  ║
║ C    ║ ccc  ║
╚══════╩══════╝
```

I need output in followwing way

```
╔══════╦════════════╗
║ COL1 ║ TOTALCOUNT ║
╠══════╬════════════╣
║ A    ║          3 ║
║ B    ║          2 ║
║ C    ║          3 ║
╚══════╩════════════╝
```

I need an exact query in sql server 2008.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to use `GROUP BY` and `COUNT()`

```
SELECT  col1, COUNT(*) totalCount
FROM    tableName
GROUP   BY col1
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0294c/1)